# Positioning issue with gallery images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a gallery in my html file and the following Problem:

The image are displayed nicely, the only problem is the second row, where 3 of the images "slip down". Here is a picture:

[image: Images are not inline with the others]

I have tried to solve this with a flex box, but I don't quite get how to use it.
By the way, the site will not go online because I don't have the rights to use the pictures.
It's just to learn.

Code:

```css
section p {
    margin-left: 5%;
}


section p iframe {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}




div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 2em;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<section>
       
       <p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/f2aSCvUhUBc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>The Witcher 3 ist eines der imposantesten Rollenspiele des 21. Jahrhunderts und nicht ohne Grund<br>mit über 800 Awards ausgezeichnet worden.<br>Das Spiel handelt vom Hexer Geralt, der die Welt vor dem weissen Frost bewahren soll,<br>besser gesagt soll dies seine Ciri (Cirilla), ein Kind des älteren Blutes und Tochter des Kaisers von Nilfgaard. Nur älteres Blut vermag den Frost aufzuhalten.<br>Doch dieses Spiel ist soviel mehr als nur eine Storyline:<br>Das Spiel lebt von einer dynamischen Welt, die sich ständig ändert, je nach dem, was Geralt im Laufe des Spiels für Entscheidungen trifft.<br> Insgesamt gibt es 36 verschiedene Enden und die NPCs verleihen dem Spiel ebenso viel Leben, wie die Musik, die Geräusche, die Landschaft und die sogenannte 40-Sekunden-Regel.<br>Diese besagt, dass im Spiel alle 40 Sekunden irgendetwas Spannendes passieren muss,<br>um den Spieler zu fesseln. Sei es ein Monster, eine vorbeirennende Rehherde oder ein umherstreifender Bandit.<br>Alles im Spiel ist kontext-sensitiv und hat Folgen, alles ist bis ins Kleinste durchdacht und hängt irgendwie zusammen.<br>Dieses Meisterwerk bietet wesentlich mehr, als so mancher Ego-Shooter und dergleichen.</p>
       
       
       <br style="clear:both;" />
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3_en_wallpaper_hearts_of_stone_olgierd_1920x1200_1446735934.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/B1VXMu9UhiS.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/Tw3_Blood_and_Wine_cover_art.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/B1GDw8ra8QS.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3-new-game-plus-screenshot.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/1._Some_creatures_will_be_more_prone_to_inflammation_than_others._The_Igni_singn_works_perfectly_on_the_fiend..jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>  
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/NBFHut1.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/NEW_The_Witcher_3_Wild_Hunt_Ice_Giant_Hunt.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3-turm-screen.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/The-Witcher-3-9.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/wwh-3-1.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/2.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
</section>
```

Comment: In your fiddle its work fine.!

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately not in my html file

Comment: if you are using floats, as it looks like, and some just have a bigger height because of the text, the beneath items will display at the right of that bigger item. It's a common problem with floats while trying to use this kind of grids. If you want to enter the flexbox, i recommend this simple tutorial! helped me a lot! http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to non-consistent height in your responsive box while you float them around, to fix this you will need to use pseudo class `:nth-of-type`
to clear the floats after every sixth element.

```
.responsive:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

**Example:**

```css
section p {
    margin-left: 5%;
}


section p iframe {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2%;
}




div.gallery {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.responsive {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}

.responsive:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section>
       
       <p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/f2aSCvUhUBc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>The Witcher 3 ist eines der imposantesten Rollenspiele des 21. Jahrhunderts und nicht ohne Grund<br>mit über 800 Awards ausgezeichnet worden.<br>Das Spiel handelt vom Hexer Geralt, der die Welt vor dem weissen Frost bewahren soll,<br>besser gesagt soll dies seine Ciri (Cirilla), ein Kind des älteren Blutes und Tochter des Kaisers von Nilfgaard. Nur älteres Blut vermag den Frost aufzuhalten.<br>Doch dieses Spiel ist soviel mehr als nur eine Storyline:<br>Das Spiel lebt von einer dynamischen Welt, die sich ständig ändert, je nach dem, was Geralt im Laufe des Spiels für Entscheidungen trifft.<br> Insgesamt gibt es 36 verschiedene Enden und die NPCs verleihen dem Spiel ebenso viel Leben, wie die Musik, die Geräusche, die Landschaft und die sogenannte 40-Sekunden-Regel.<br>Diese besagt, dass im Spiel alle 40 Sekunden irgendetwas Spannendes passieren muss,<br>um den Spieler zu fesseln. Sei es ein Monster, eine vorbeirennende Rehherde oder ein umherstreifender Bandit.<br>Alles im Spiel ist kontext-sensitiv und hat Folgen, alles ist bis ins Kleinste durchdacht und hängt irgendwie zusammen.<br>Dieses Meisterwerk bietet wesentlich mehr, als so mancher Ego-Shooter und dergleichen.</p>
       
       
       <br style="clear:both;" />
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3_en_wallpaper_hearts_of_stone_olgierd_1920x1200_1446735934.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/B1VXMu9UhiS.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/Tw3_Blood_and_Wine_cover_art.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x500/000/fff" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="600" height="500">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/B1GDw8ra8QS.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3-new-game-plus-screenshot.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/1._Some_creatures_will_be_more_prone_to_inflammation_than_others._The_Igni_singn_works_perfectly_on_the_fiend..jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>  
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/NBFHut1.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div> 
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/NEW_The_Witcher_3_Wild_Hunt_Ice_Giant_Hunt.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/witcher3-turm-screen.png">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/The-Witcher-3-9.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/wwh-3-1.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
       
       
       
       
    <div class="responsive">
      <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="resources/img/2.jpg">
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
       
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using floating elements you got to have all the elements as same height otherwise they will starting acting like this.

Try giving height to the elements, see if it works.

Comment: Ok, so I made the div.gallery img and the .responsive class have a height of 150px, gave the .responsive class a width of 25% and gave it a margin-top of 5em.
Now it works but I don't know if I solved the problem in a proper way. What do you think?

Comment: With float there is only so much you can do. But again even with flexbox if you want them all to be aligned they will end up being same height.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `responsive` class to this:

```
.responsive {
    padding: 2em;
    width: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of what was already said (fiddle is working and the problem probably appears due to undefined height) if you want to use flexbox, then you need to add the property `flex-wrap:wrap`. If you want to understand flexbox better here is a link that explains pretty well: [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Also if by any chance the fixed height is not working then you need to inspect that area (right click on the area and click on „inspect element”) and see what is there blocking the other images(on the element section). Using the browser console is very important for front end debugging.

Answer (score 0):

also try this.its work for me

```
<div class="rowrow"><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Amrish Patel</h3>
                                            <p>CEO and Managing Director</p>
                                          <p>CEO and Managing Director</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Amit Goyal</h3>
                                            <p>Chief Technical Officer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Dimple Goyal</h3>
                                            <p>Software Engineer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="i{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Nisarg Patel</h3>
                                            <p>Full Stack Developer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Nikita Sarang</h3>
                                            <p>Software Engineer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Reshma Bhagwani</h3>
                                            <p>Software Engineer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Dhruvi Kothari</h3>
                                            <p>Software Engineer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Darshit Patel</h3>
                                            <p>Front-end Developer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Ghanshyam Prajapati</h3>
                                            <p>Front-end Developer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Ravi Pitroda</h3>
                                            <p>Software Engineer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div><div class="item">
                                    <article>
                                        <div><img src="{{ 'itemimg.jpg' | asset_url }}"></div>
                                        <div class="boxContent team-box-border">
                                            <h3>Radhesh Vayeda</h3>
                                            <p>Full Stack Developer</p>
                                        </div>

                                    </article>
                                </div>


                            </div>
```

and css

```
 .item {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    text-align: center;
}
```